# QCompleter not support up and down key

Tags: c++, qt, qcompleter

I use `setEditable(true)` to make `QComboBox` editable, when I input `cy`, then the completer's popup view will be visible and lists all possible results like: `cyan`, `cyana`, `liecyan` ... But when I press Down in keyboard (`Qt::Key_Down`), the first one `cyan` will be selected and QComboBox's lineedit's text will be set `cyan` , meanwhile, completer's popup view updates, only `cyan` shows. How can I customize it to make it behave like web's `select` component.

Comment: Is it a QLineEdit with QCompleter or is it an editable QComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question.

1.`class MyListView : public QListView`

2.`MyListView's bool event(...)` need to be implemented to concern about type is `QEvent::ShortcutOverride`

3.based on `QEvent::ShortcutOverride`, when user press `Qt:Key_Up` or `Qt::Key_Down`,set`falg` false, when user release key,set `flag` true

3.`QCompleter` use setPopup(`MyListView`'s instance) to override default listview
4. set QCompleter's regexp to work when `falg` is true
5.I got what I want